# How can I create a table with different fields from different events?

Tags: splunk

After we process a client file, we get event in splunk as shown in below snapshot.

[image]

From these events I want to build a table something like below.

[image]

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below query to generate expected dashboard.

> source="*sc-*.log*" AND SMARTCONNECT_TRANSACTION_RESULT |stats
>   values(CLIENT_ID) as "Client Name" values(ERP_WP_PAYSTATEMENTS) as
>   "Paystatements from ERP" values(CDM_WP_PAYSTATEMENTS) as
>   "Paystatements in CDM" values(CDM_EE_LIEN_COUNT) as "Liens in CDM"
>   values(ARFF_WP_PAYSTATEMENTS) as "Paystatements Generated by ARFF"
>   values(ARFF_EE_LIEN_COUNT) as  "Liens generated by ARFF" by
>   TransactionID

credits: Splunk team